# Dynamically change custom list item background

Tags: android

I am creating a custom list view with favorite functionality, but I don't know how to change favorite image background on click. When I simply change the background of favorite icon than it automatically change background of another favorite image background at the time of scrolling. Please check below code :

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList<Customlist> list;
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###");

public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Customlist> list) {
    activity = a;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.list = list;

}

public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView txt_unit, txt_state, txt_price, term_left, customr;
    TextView install_date;
    final ImageView fav;
    View view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    customr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.customr);
    txt_state = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_state);
    install_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.install_date);
    term_left = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.term_left);
    txt_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
    fav = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fav);
    txt_unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_unit);

    fav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // fav = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R)

            fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favourite_select);

            Toast.makeText(activity, "click", 1).show();

        }
    });

    // set values
    customr.setText(list.get(position).getCUSTOMER());
    txt_state.setText(list.get(position).getSTATE_NAME());
    install_date.setText(list.get(position).getINSTALL_DATE());
    term_left.setText(list.get(position).getTREM_LEFT());
    String price = formatter.format(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position)
            .getRUPEES()));



    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you need to implement the adapter on ViewHolder pattern:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHoldler holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(
                R.layout.frag_home_gridview_item, null, false);
        holder = new ViewHoldler();
        holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.gridview_item_label);
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.gridview_item_name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHoldler) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tv.setText(getItem(position));
    holder.iv.setImageResource(this.ids[position]);
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHoldler {
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tv;
}
```

**Second**, use `partial refreshment mechanism` to change the target `View`'s `background`:

```
private void refreshPartially(int position){
    int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastVisiblePosition = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
    if(position>=firstVisiblePosition && position<=lastVisiblePosition){
        View view = listview.getChildAt(position - firstVisiblePosition);
        if(view.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder){
            ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            //holder.play.setBackgroundResource(resId);//Do something here.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Third**, add `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             refreshPartially(position);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the adapter on ViewHolder pattern:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Still getting the same problem.What I have to change in my code? It's urgent. 
final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  if (convertView == null) {
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

} else {
   view = convertView;
   ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).fav.setTag(list.get(position));
  }

Comment: see SilentKnight's answer. He has created ViewHolder. You need to create ViewHolder class and include all the views of your custom list item in it and then follow the implementation in getView accordingly.

Comment: I know this is very common and simple problem but yes, I have created ViewHolder class and added all the views inside holder class.I don't know what I am doing wrong? I have pull to refresh kind of listview , so it will hold image background of same position?